# Is "evidenter" the correct translation for "obviously!"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary, adverb

I've searched the forum but found no answer to my question.
How would one say obviously in Latin?
As in answering a question with a "it's option b, obviously!"
Online dictionaries have given me all sorts of possible translations
and I don't have a clue which one is the correct option.
Would it be *evidenter*?

Comment: Can you tell us a more concrete version of the kind of situation you have in mind—a little story where someone wants to say this? That will help us find appropriate Latin. I think, though, that most of the synonyms fit most situations: *[scilicet](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Latin_Synonyms_with_Their_Different_Sign/blhFAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=scilicet), plane, certe, sane, quippe, nempe, vere, clare, videlicet* —hmm, there are indeed a lot! *Nimirum*, literally "no wonder", might best carry the insinuation that the question need not have been asked.

Comment: @BenKovitz Thank you for your answer.
The exact example is the one I've mentioned
You have a question with multiple answers and must choose the correct one.
Someone asks you which one is the correct answer, and you answer "option X, obviously!" because the other options are not even related to the topic at hand so there's absolutely no doubt that the correct one is X.

Comment: Hi Iza! You seem to have created two accounts. [You can follow these instructions to merge them.](https://latin.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) Having this question connected to your registered account allows you to respond by comments and edit your question.

Comment: Here are some examples to show what I mean, and how widely this can vary. Roommate A: "Did you take out the trash, yes or no?", referring to the overflowing garbage can in plain sight. Roommate B: "No, obviously!", admitting guilt and sarcastically implying an unwillingness to do it (as opposed to "No, obviously. Sorry, I forgot."). Teacher pointing to an exam question, which reads: "Which is a solution to x^2 + 2 = 11: 3 or b?" Student: "3, obviously!" A happy demonstration of understanding. If a student asks and the teacher answers that way, it might be insulting, depending on intonation.

Answer (score 3):

Ben Kovitz listed some relevant words in his comment and Sebastian Koppehel added some more.
In the case you mention ("this option is obviously correct") I think the most natural option is to use and adverb derived from an adjective.
The others feel too weak for such an emphatic use, much like "indeed" is weaker (and otherwise different too) than "obviously".
More importantly, you seem to want to use the word independently rather than as a part of a sentence, and that rules out many words.
I don't think you could just cry out *Quippe!*…

The candidates seem to be:

- *Clare*: brightly, clearly, aloud
- *Sane*: healthily, well, truly, certainly
- *Vere*: truthfully
- *Certe*: certainly, surely
- *Plane*: plainly, simply, clearly
- *Evidenter*: evidently, manifestly
- *Manifesto*: clearly, evidently, manifestly
- *Aperte*: openly, clearly, plainly

I think the ones that come closest in tone to "obviously" are ***manifesto*** (from [*manifestus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=manifestus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)) ***plane*** (from [*planus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=planus1&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)).
The one you mention, ***evidenter*** (from [*evidens*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=evidens&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)), is also a good option.
See the linked dictionary entries for more details on my top candidates.
None of the three match "obviously" perfectly, but they are the closest I can think of for the use case you have.

Comment: Other options: *manifesto, aperte, palam*

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Thanks! I like *manifesto* a lot for this use.

Comment: The level of sarcasm that the OP wants still isn't clear to me, but don't _scilicet_ and _videlicet_ carry this kind of meaning?

Comment: @BenKovitz Not to my knowledge, and I don't think they can be used in isolation. But I'd be happy to be proven wrong!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the adverbial forms given by Joonas, you could also use an impersonal construction like this:

> Patet X rectum responsum esse.

Or even more forcefully:

> X rectum responsum esse solis luce clarius est.
> *It is clearer than sunlight that X is the correct answer.*

Comment: Do you think it's possible to cry out "Patet!" akin to using "Obviously!" in isolation? The OP's use case looks more like that.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta That sounds *satis Latine* to me, although I know no direct example. I did find this from Cicero though (in the L&S entry for *pateo*): Quid porro quaerendum est? factumne sit? at constat: a quo? at patet. (Nice how one accidentally comes across these little vignettes of Ciceronian rhetoric just browsing the dictionary. He really was good.)